# Why am I getting the "Equations for ... have different numbers of arguments" message?

Tags: haskell

The following function compiles and works:

```
shares :: Maybe (Int, L.ByteString) -> Maybe Int                                                                                                                                                            
shares a =                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    case a of                                                                                                                                                                                               
        Nothing        -> Nothing                                                                                                                                                                           
        Just (x, y)    -> Just x
```

But when rewritten in the following form:

```
shares :: Maybe (Int, L.ByteString) -> Maybe Int                                                                                                                                                            
shares Nothing = Nothing                                                                                                                                                                                    
shares Just (x, y) = Just x
```

I get errors

```
Equations for ‘shares’ have different numbers of arguments
```

I think it's same essentially.

Answer (score 8):

In Haskell, arguments to function are separated by spaces. Therefore, the last equation has two arguments: `Just` of type `a -> Maybe a` and `(x, y)` of type `(Int, L.ByteString)`. Since you want one argument, it should instead read:

```
shares (Just (x, y)) = Just x
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.